# limit admin rights to documents I created in couchdb

Tags: php, database, couchdb, nosql

I'm struggling finding documentation on how to manage user rights in a db at the document level. I'm making a web app similar to "instagram" (not really, but close enough for this discussion). Users can write records/documents, and ALL users can view ALL entries. BUT, I want to show "Joe created this entry", "Sally Created this Other Entry" BUT, I don't want Sally to be able to make records that look like Joe created them. FINALLY, Joe and Sally can only delete documents they own.

One more hoop (because people have suggested using a single db for each user...), I want to be able to say, SHOW ALL DOCUMENTS across all users... ... I'm really confused. I understand how to create db's and how to create and update users. And I like the idea of a simple REST EndPoint for getting all my records AND the horizontal scaleability of CouchDB so would like to use it for this application...

HELP? Direction?

Comment: Did you consider to enforce permissions on the PHP layer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand all your requirements, but it looks to me like the vlaidate_doc_update might help you. Here are some examples: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html

Other references: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation

(The latter one is more up to date.)

As you can get a UserCtx and secObj (securioty Object) that might be the best point to make sure that users are allowed to edit data at document level.

Chris

Edit By @janl: even more docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=validate_doc_update#validate-document-update-functions

Comment: Hi Nathan, could you find some useful information in the links or do you have any further questions?